# Printer doesn't print after replacing black PCU

Tags: printer, ink

The black photoconductor unit (PCU) on my Ricoh Aficio SP C420DN will not print black after it was replaced. The correct part was used, and I ordered another one and replaced it again hoping that would fix it. It didn't.

Does anyone know why it would quit after replacing the black PCU and possibly what else I would need to replace? I followed the directions and was very careful, with minimal exposure to light. I should also mention that it will print color still.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you removed the PCU, there would have been at least one or two tabs or strips that you need to remove before you can use it in the machine. You may have missed one.

Check the packaging (the stock ones have it printing on the box) and double-check you've removed all the tabs etc you need to. They'll be in a different color than the rest of the black plastic shell.

If that fails, I'll call a technician - it is possible (but admittedly not particularly likely) that you've damaged something internally, like dislodging a sensor or catching on a wire somewhere.